# “user: Current not implemented on linux/amd64” with fresh golang on fedora

Tags: go, fedora, home-directory

`user.Current()` doesn't work on a fresh Fedora golang. No cross-compiling involved. Just straight `go install` and run. Works fine on Ubuntu and a custom slackware dist. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of the `go version` command?

Comment: 1.3.3. Apparently this is a known redhat issue. Perhaps it is trying to use cgo?

Comment: Oy. Not sure if this is helpful but: if it's in your own code, you could possibly *write* some cgo to get the current user via `getlogin_r` or something, or, if this is a once-on-startup type thing and you really badly want to avoid cgo, actually run the system's `uname` binary and read its output or something (understanding that that's like 100x more expensive). If it's in third-party code that you don't want to patch, I wonder if building golang locally from source (ack, sorry) might get around it.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is if something's caused it to cross-compile when it doesn't need to be, e.g., maybe gcc/g++ are not installed, or it's a 32-bit golang install on a 64-bit box. These are definitely wild stabs in the dark and last-ditch ideas (hence comments not an answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in fedora: [Bug 1135152](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1135152)

If you compile the Go program using `gccgo`, rather than `golang` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like user.Current() ultimately calls [getuid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html) from libc, does he have it installed? Is it the 64 bit rpm?